# Удаление слова с наибольшим количеством слогов из строки с++

Tags: c++

Нужно реализовать удаление слова с наибольшим количеством слогов из строки с++. Вот код, который разбивает все слова в строке на слоги, но реализовать удаление не получилось(

```
#include <iostream>
//Подключение библиотеки строковых функций:
//memset(), strcpy(), strlen(), strncat()
//их описание легко найти в сети
#include <string.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
//Для вывода русских символов на консоль (см. setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus"))
#include <clocale>
//Делаем глобальным пространство имен стандартных шаблонов
using namespace std;
//Глобальные константы для длин вспомогательных текстовых буферов
#define SUBL 512
#define BIGL 4096
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция IsVowel возвращает 1 (истина), если проверяемый символ letter
//является гласной буквой русского алфавита и 0 (ложь) в противном
//случае
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool IsVowel(char letter){
    char l = tolower(letter);//приводим символ к нижнему регистру А->а
    char a[] = "аоэиуыеёюя";//10
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)//по очереди проверяем
        if(a[i] == l) return true;//является ли символ l одним из a[i]
    return false;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция IsConsonant возвращает 1 (истина), если проверяемый символ letter
//является согласной буквой русского алфавита и 0 (ложь) в противном
//случае
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool IsConsonant(char letter){
    char l = tolower(letter);//приводим символ к нижнему регистру А->а
    char a[] = "бвгдйжзклмнпрстфхцчшщ";//21
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
        if(a[i] == l) return true;
    return false;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция IsLetter возвращает 1 (истина), если проверяемый символ letter
//является буквой русского алфавита и 0 (ложь) в противном
//случае
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool IsLetter(char letter){
    char l = tolower(letter);//приводим символ к нижнему регистру А->а
    char a[] = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщыъьэюя";//33
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
        if(a[i] == l) return true;
    return false;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция ContainVowel возвращает 1 (истина), если в строке str
//есть гласная буква русского алфавита и 0 (ложь) в противном
//случае
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool ContainVowel(char *str){
    for(int k=0;k<strlen(str);k++)
        if(IsVowel(str[k])) return true;
    return false;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция InsertDash вставляет тире в позицию pos строки str
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void InsertDash(char *str,int pos){
    int n = strlen(str);
    for(int i=n+1;i>pos;i--)
        str[i] = str[i-1];
    str[pos] = '-';
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция GetWord выделяет из текста str первое
//встреченное в ней слово
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char* GetWord(char* str,char* buf){
    memset(buf,'\0',SUBL);//заполняем буфер нулями
    int i=0, j=0, n = strlen(str);
    //пропускаем не буквы
    while (!IsLetter(str[i]) && i < n)
        i++;
    //а буквы не пропускаем
    while (IsLetter(str[i]) && i < n){
        buf[j] = str[i];
        i++; j++;
    }
    return buf;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция SubString возвращает фрагмент строки начиная с символа
//в позиции pos и длиной len
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char* SubString(char* str, char* buf, int pos, int len){
    int n = strlen(str), i, j = 0, a = len + pos;
    memset(buf,'\0',SUBL);//заполняем буфер нулями

    if(len == 0 || a > n) a = n;//контроль выхода за границы

    for(i=pos;i<a;i++,j++)//копируем элементы в подстроку
        buf[j] = str[i];

    return buf;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция SplitWord - главная функция, которая разбивает слово str
//на слоги и возвращает группу слогов разделенных тире
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char* SplitWord(char* str,char* buf){
    char sub[SUBL];
    memset(sub,'\0',SUBL);//заполняем буфер нулями
    strcpy (buf,str);
    int pos = 0, len = strlen(str), i = 1;
    while(i < len){
        if(i+2 < len){
            //проверка первого условия из задания
            // сг-гx (x - хотя бы одна буква)
            if(IsConsonant(str[i-1]) && IsVowel(str[i]) &&
               IsVowel(str[i+1]) ){
                InsertDash(buf,i+1+pos);
                pos++;
            } else
                //проверка второго условия из задания
                // гс-сy (y - имеется хотя бы одна гласная)
                if(IsVowel(str[i-1]) && IsConsonant(str[i]) && IsConsonant(str[i+1]) &&
                   ContainVowel(SubString(str,sub,i+2,0))){
                    InsertDash(buf,i+1+pos);
                    pos++;
                } else
                    //проверка третьего условия из задания
                    // xг-y  (y - имеется хотя бы одна гласная)
                    if(IsLetter(str[i-1]) && IsVowel(str[i]) &&
                       ContainVowel(SubString(str,sub,i+1,2))){
                        InsertDash(buf,i+1+pos);
                        pos++;
                    }
            //обработка случая, когда два первых символа гласные
            if(i == 1 && IsVowel(str[i-1])  &&
               ContainVowel(SubString(str,sub,i,2))){
                InsertDash(buf,i);
                pos++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return buf;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Функция Processing принимает строку str, которая может состоять
//из нескольких слов и возвращает строку с разбитыми на слоги словами
//Эту простую функцию мы будем вызывать в main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char* Processing(char* str,char* buf){
    int start, end  = strlen(str), j=0, i=0;
    char buf1[SUBL], buf2[SUBL], buf3[SUBL], *word = NULL;
    memset(buf,'\0',BIGL);//заполняем буфер нулями
    while(i < end){
        //Вставка знаков препинания
        //если не буква, значит знак препинания
        while(!IsLetter(str[i]) && i < end){
            buf[j] = str[i];
            i++; j++;
        }
        start = i;
        //Получение очередного слова
        word = GetWord(SubString(str,buf1,start,end),buf3);
        i += strlen(word);
        //Разбивка на слоги
        //копируем разбитое слово в буфер
        strcpy (buf1,SplitWord(word,buf2));
        //вставляем слово из буфера в результирующую строку
        strncat(buf,buf1,strlen(buf1));
        j += strlen(buf1);
        //Конец разбивки на слоги
    }
    return buf;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Эта команда позволяет выводить русские символы на консоль
    //забей в гугл "вывод русских символов на консоль C++"
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    char buf[BIGL];//Объявляем вспомогательный текстовый буфер
    char text[] =
        "Пример текста слова которого надо разбить на слоги.";
    cout << text << endl;
    cout << Processing(text,buf) << endl;
    char text1[] =
        "Гарри Поттер Маша Троттер Карл Поппер дезоксирибонуклеиновая.";
    cout << text1 << endl;
    cout << Processing(text1,buf) << endl;
    //system("cls") - использовать незачем
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: нужно иметь предикат определяющий гласная буква или нет,  а потом  пройдя  по исходной строке от начала до конца,  добавить пробел перед негласными буквами, если следующая тоже не такая, а если тоже такая, то ставить пробел между ними(тут просто нужно знать саму граматику разбиения на слоги). А потом  этой модифицированной  строкой инициализируем обьект istringstream,  а оттуда уже вводим в вектор строк или выводим на экран

Comment: Посчитать слоги в слове,  еще легче чем просто разбить на слоги, т.е. посчитать количество негласных букв, которые не находятся рядом, начиная от второго элемента.

Comment: Количество слогов определяется количеством гласных.

Comment: @MindCleaner ,  и как же вы собираетесь разбивать на 5 слог слово MindCleaner ?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я не собираюсь разбивать.

Comment: я понел, но я не читал ваш код, подход не тот. Предложу вам свой вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
// проверяем символ на негласность
bool is_non_vowel(char ch)
{
    char s = toupper(ch);
    string t = "AEIOUY"; // в строке просто все гласные буквы
    size_t k = t.find(s);
    return k == string::npos;
}
// считаем слоги в слове
int syll_count( const string& s)
{
    int k = 0;
    auto It = s.begin(), end = s.end();
    // в конце могут быть несколько негласных
    while(is_non_vowel(*(end - 1)) && end != It)
          --end;
    while (It != end) {
        // учитывает факт рядом находящихся негласных
        while (is_non_vowel(*It))
            ++It;
        It = find_if(It, end, is_non_vowel);
            ++k;
    }
    return k;
}
void delete_word_By_Condition(string& s)
{
    istringstream is(s);
    vector<string> vstr;
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(is), istream_iterator<string>(), 
    back_inserter(vstr));
    vector<int> v(vstr.size());
    // количество слог для каждого слова заносим в вектор
    generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [vstr]() {static auto It = vstr.begin();
        int i = syll_count(*It); ++It; return i;});
    // находим индекс наибольшего элемента
    size_t n = max_element(v.begin(), v.end()) - v.begin();
    auto first = s.begin();
    while (n--) {
        first = find(first, s.end(), ' ');
        while(*first == ' ')
            ++first;
    }
    s.erase(first, find(first, s.end(), ' '));
}
int main()
{    
    string str = "Normally, we teach on Khan Academy using videos, but here in programming land";
    delete_word_By_Condition(str);
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: однако  удобнее в функции проделать все, изменю

Comment: В строке "copy(istream_iterator<string>(is), istream_iterator<string>(), 
    back_inserter(vstr));" почему-то выдает ошибки:
istream_iterator - неиспользованный идентификатор
string- использование имени типа не допускается

Comment: попробуйте подключить библиотеку  #include <iterator>

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: Рад что помог, но  еслиб вы нажали на стрельку или галочку, то это было бы за место спасибо

Comment: Спустя некоторое время появился вопрос, можно ли реализовать программу не через вектора, а через char?